# Know when user takes photo with the Camera Android

Tags: android, camera

I wanted to know if it was possible for an app to know if user took a photo with the Android camera and send a push notification or start the app if it is activated.

Comment: dont think so.  you need your app running so it can monitor new images in the cameras folder.  but the again not 100% sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ~1.5 billion Android devices in use, spanning thousands of device models. These will have hundreds, if not thousands, of "Android camera apps", including pre-installed ones and ones installed by users. None have to tell third-party apps when they take a picture, and none have to publish any evidence that they took a picture. For example, they can take a picture and upload it straight to a Web server.

So, no, this is not possible in any reliable fashion.